# Tkinter frame class using OOP not showing parameters e.g. background colour (bg="black etc.)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, python-3.7

I am new to OOP with Tkinter but have made some applications implementing minimal OOP from Tkinter - the classic frame1 = Frame(root, bg="black") rather than using classes.

I have tried many different ways to use inheritance of the Tkinter Frame class but it doesn't seem to be carrying out the arguments I try to parse. The buttons are working, though.

The main issue I believe is in each of the Frame classes named Menu, titleFrame, and buttonFrame. I don't think overlapping widgets is the problem, either.

The code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk): 
    def __init__(self):

        # main
        super().__init__()
        self.title("JXIS")
        self.resizable(height=False, width=False)
        
        def center_window(width=800, height=480):
            # get screen width and height
            screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
            screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()
            # calculate position x and y coordinates
            windowX = (screen_width/2) - (width/2)
            windowY = (screen_height/2) - (height/2)
            self.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (width, height, windowX, windowY))
        
        center_window()

        # widgets
        self.menu = Menu(self)
        self.titleFrame = titleFrame(self)
        self.buttonFrame = buttonFrame(self)
        self.mainloop()

class Menu(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.configure(bg="black",
                    highlightbackground="yellow",
                    highlightthickness=20,
                    relief="flat")
        self.grid()

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)#    titleFrame
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=2)#    buttonFrame
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=2)#    
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)#  
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)# titleFrame, buttonFrame
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)#

    def create_widgets(self):
        pass

class titleFrame(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        super().__init__(parent) 
        self.bg = "black" 
        self.highlightbackground="yellow" 
        self.highlightthickness=20 
        self.relief="flat"
        self.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.titleLabel = tk.Label(self,
                                text="\n   JXIS", 
                                font=("Montserrat-Alt1 Regular",20),
                                fg="white",
                                bg="black")
        self.titleLabel.grid()

class buttonFrame(tk.Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent): 
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.bg="black" 
        self.highlightbackground="yellow" 
        self.highlightthickness=2 
        self.relief="flat"

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)#    button1
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)#    
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)# button1
        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)# 
        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)#

        self.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="N,W,E,S")


        self.button1 = tk.Button(self,
                            bg="yellow",
                            activebackground="green",
                            text="Inventory",
                            compound='center',
                            relief="flat")
        self.button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="N,W,E,S", padx=[20,10], pady=[20,10])


        self.button2 = tk.Button(self,
                            bg="yellow",
                            activebackground="green",
                            text="Status",
                            compound='center',
                            relief="flat")
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="N,W,E,S", padx=[10,10], pady=[20,10])


        self.button3 = tk.Button(self,
                            bg="yellow",
                            activebackground="green",
                            text="Weather",
                            compound='center',
                            relief="flat")
        self.button3.grid(row=0,column=2, sticky="N,W,E,S", padx=[10,20], pady=20)

        self.button4 = tk.Button(self,
                            bg="yellow",
                            activebackground="green",
                            text="News",
                            compound='center',
                            relief="flat")
        self.button4.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="N,W,E,S", padx=[20,10], pady=[10,20])


        self.button5 = tk.Button(self,
                            bg="yellow",
                            activebackground="green",
                            text="Notes",
                            compound='center',
                            relief="flat")
        self.button5.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="N,W,E,S", padx=[10,10], pady=[10,20])

App()
```

I have tried to use bg="black" in the `super().__init__(parent)` section because I had seen it in a similar post, but that didn't work, likely due to them using `Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="")` for their code.

Comment: `__init__` and not __init__ (when you write '__' in stackoverflow it bolds the text)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just set an attribute like `self.bg`. You need to call the `configure` method. For example:

```
self.configure(background="black")
```

You can also include these when calling `super().__init__`:

```
class titleFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, background="black")
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have followed your advice and some of the frames now look better aka they work, but the Menu class ( the main frame with other frames inside of it) doesn't seem to take the attributes.

Comment: On some platforms you can't change the look of menus.

Comment: I named a class Menu which inherits from the tk.frame class. It's just that it doesn't seem to take a hold of the arguments I give it. Will rebuild from the parents to the child classes to see if there is any hiding / overlapping of the parent frame on the window. Thanks again.

Comment: @TheOccupator: I apologize for misunderstanding what you meant by `Menu`. The problem with the `Menu` class is that it's only 1 pixel wide and tall, so no matter what the color you won't be able to see it.